# How do I populate a spinner inside a gridview/listview?

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I am trying to populate a spinners inside of a listview.  I just don't know how to go about it.  Here is what I have but I know it's wrong.

```
`mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.custom_element,
            null,
            new String [] { RestaurantElementsTable.KEY_INGREDIENT, RestaurantElementsTable.KEY_DEFAULT_QUANITY }, 
            new int[] { R.id.textViewElement, R.id.spinnerQuanity }, 0);


    mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    eGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`
```

An example or resource that will help me solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to extend SimpleCursorAdapter and make a Custom Adapter.

You could also check out this great library:

CWAC-MergeAdapter on GitHub

. It alows you to simply add Views to an Adapter

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are setting Spinner's Adapter onto GridView. 
In Application structure, first set your gridview/listview with the adapter. 
And use this adapters GetView method to put a spinner in your layout and populate it in every item.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInf = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInf.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);
        }


Spinner spinner = (Spinner) convertView .findViewById(R.id.spinnerItem);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.travelreasons, R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```